# Missing more menu options three dots/vertical ellipsis (⋮) within administration interfaces

Tags: custom-fields, admin

I've created some custom data and fields that I now need to delete, but I don't see any options for deletion- only the option to add. Also, I'm unable to edit a custom data group once it's created.

I've also noticed additional administration options are also missing in other CiviCRM administration interfaces e.g. membership renewal, delete, auto-renewal and billing detail options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have CiviCRM shoreditch extension enabled on your site than try adding below line in your theme css file

```
.crm-container span.btn-slide {
    display: unset !important;
}
```

Thanks
Pradeep

Comment: The Shoreditch css? or Drupal?

Comment: Drupal theme custom css file...

Comment: Not every site has a Drupal theme custom css file. And to have to subtheme bartik or seven just to get Shoreditch to work is quite a task. There is a community contributed PR in the queue for Shoreditch dating back to June. Getting that merged is the real solution here.

Comment: I installed the "Asset Injector" module in Drupal and added this CSS. I can now see the options for Custom Data and Custom Fields! Thanks!

Will this fix affect any other missing options, or are the selectors specific to the Custom Data/Fields pages?

Comment: They are affecting on most of the page listings, like on manage events, profile listing, contribution pages etc So could you mark this answered if it resolved your issue?

Comment: This is very much a very temporary solution. 

Comment: @karin yes its a temp solution. But permanent solution would to be fix the shoreditch theme extension

Comment: Thanks for the suggested fix - for others we found `display: inline-flex !important;` worked better with our admin theme

Comment: So now I'm having trouble with CiviCase- buttons do nothing and other issues. I tried the "display: inline-flex !important;" but still no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Shoreditch is officially designed to work with 5.24.2 so expect issues when running it with the latest CiviCRM security release.

You may just want to disable it!

Comment: I do- it was required for an extension. Don't think I can disable?

Comment: Which Extension requires it? What you can do is disable it -> Delete the Custom Field (or what you want to do) and then re-enable it again.

Comment: It's required for CiviCase and when I try to disable it won't let me.

Comment: Is there any way to use CiviCRM without Shoreditch?

Comment: CiviCRM -> yes - absolutely - one does not need Shoreditch to yse CiviCRM though some Extensions may have require it.

Comment: M<y install won't allow me to use CiviCase without Shoreditch. I hoped there was some kind of workaround :(

Comment: If the CiviCase you’re using is the one by Compucorp - they are also the ones who author Shoreditch (and thus require it) - you’re best bet is to convince them to issue a release that is compatible with at minimum latest CiviCRM security release.